# SPO Modern: How to inject and execute webpart programmatically, using js?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extension

I have only the URL of webpart (example 'https://sitename.com/sites/site-colection/ClientSideAssets/hereisguid/webpartname.js') and I need to inject and run it programmatically via js, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's not officially supported but You can use global variable (available on every modern page) _spComponentLoader. The problem is - it requires You to provide WebPartContext which You cannot simply get outside of SPFx.

If You want to do it in SPFx here is a sample code:

webPartId = hereisguid from Your url

```
        let component = await _spComponentLoader.loadComponentById(webPartId);
        let manifest = _spComponentLoader.tryGetManifestById(webPartId);
        let wpInstance = new component.default();
        context.manifest = manifest;
        //@ts-ignore
        context._domElement = document.getElementById("<id-of-element-you-want-wp-to-render-in>")
        await wpInstance._internalInitialize(context, {}, 1);
        wpInstance._properties = webPart.properties;

        await wpInstance.onInit();
        wpInstance.render();
        wpInstance._renderedOnce = true;
```

Again - I don't think it's supported so try it on Your own risk.
Note this web part must be available at the site You are going to execute this script.